# WSO2 Identity Server - Publish to cluster of PDP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've created a cluster of PDP instances for a highly available authorization service. I've tested that adding a PDP to the cluster (i.e. starting it configured with same database as other PDP in the cluster) will automatically "publish" the same policies that are published on the other PDP. That's ideal, but how do I go about publishing policy changes to all PDP in the cluster?

The only way I see to publish policies from my PAP is to register each PDP as a "subscriber" and publish to all subscribers. This isn't ideal because I want my cluster to be scalable, so subscribers will change dynamically, and it isn't acceptable to register them individually.